# clone two Maps with deepclone()

Tags: apex, map, clone

I have a Map with Date Like Key and all Event on that day as a List of values. 
Here the code I use to create the map:

```
Map<Date,List<Event>> mappaeventidate= new Map<Date,List<Event>>(); 
    for(Event e:eventi_tutti){
        if(!mappaeventidate.containsKey(e.StartDateTime.date())){
            mappaeventidate.put(e.StartDateTime.date(),new List<Event>{e});
        }else{
            mappaeventidate.get(e.StartDateTime.date()).add(e);
        }           
    }
```

Now I need to clone the map, and after  to delete the map I created before. I'm trying to use deepclone but I have a error.
Here my code:

```
Map<Date,List<Event>> mappaeventidate2 =mappaeventidate.deepClone();
```

and the error when I save the trigger:

```
Operation only applies to SObject value map types: Map<Date,List<Event>>
```

I need to delete the List of Events inside the Map but before I want to store them in another Map. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need to delete the events, or just clear the map?

Comment: delete this events and after few operations reinsert them again

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem with this code.

```
Map<Date,List<Event>> mappaeventtwo= new Map<Date,List<Event>>(); 
    for(Date d:mappaeventidate.keySet()){
        mappaeventtwo.put(d, mappaeventidate.get(d).deepClone());
    }
```

if anyone needs it

Comment: Thanks mate. This was really helpful.